# How to deploy install of MS SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition via command-line script - not working

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2017, command-line, windows-10

I'm trying to deploy `MS SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition` via command-line script from a server share that holds the install media onto Windows 10 1803 (June release). However, I'm not having much luck. I'm pushing the script to the individual clients from a KACE "KBox" K1000 running the latest version (9.0.270). The installer fails at the get-go because it thinks I'm trying to install a feature not supported by the version of SQL Server. However, I got my information from Microsoft. I'm at a loss because I can't find documentation on the errors that are being reported.

Here's a snip of the Output Log generated at run-time on the "KBox":

[image: Output Log]

I tried removing all references to AS and IS in the command statement, so that it would read:

```
\\AppServerBox\SQLServer2017Media\Developer_ENU\SETUP.EXE /QS
/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=Install /ENU=True
/FEATURES=SQL,Tools /UpdateEnabled=0 /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER
/SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
/SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="\Everyone"
/AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
/AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD="password"
```

and ran it in an elevated command prompt, directly on the client, and got this error again:

[image]

Some documentation said that Java JRE [1.7 or 1.8] is necessary, so I installed 1.8. This didn't seem to help. I keep getting the same error. Hopefully, someone can help resolve this issue before it's too late. Classes will be starting soon.

Comment: The user who runs the script has select and execute permissions on windows share?

Comment: Yes, the appropriate users have Read and Execute permissions on the share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the error is states the reason which seems fairly self-explanatory:

> You have selected a feature that is not supported for Windows Server Core... [Features Supported]

One of your input arguments is `SQL` [which translates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-2017#Feature) into:

- SQL Engine
- Replication
- Fulltext
- DQ
- Polybase
- Advanced Analytics (R)
- R Packages

Instead of putting `SQL` in the features list, only put what you need. If what you need isn't supported on Windows Core, then don't install on Windows core.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was certain it must be something simple. However, I need to know if there is a Microsoft page that lists what is and what isn't supported on Windows Core, because I don't know. I got my settings from the "/?" help in the installer, and it doesn't list these things. There is documentation to list these things out on the web, but no explanation as to what is supported on Windows Core. A manual Basic Install works, but then I don't know what exactly I'm getting that works, and we should be able to script it and push it to already installed machines. Thanks.

Comment: Found the information for Server Core and installation was successful; just need to do some more testing. Thanks.